# Change selected Tab after CRUD operation - Ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

The app is a simple workout entry tool. It does basic API call for CRUD operations. [App Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA7LW.png)

I can't reload the Workout Tab after a new entry is created and stored to the database. I was able to manipulate NavController to set root for it to display the updated data but it's only under the Add Workout tab. [Workouts updated in Add Workout tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8GUE.png) When I tab back to Workout tab. It displays the result as the first image attached.

I presume this is because the constructor and NgOnInit are initialized only once. How can I get around this?

This is the code for the Workout tab.

```
export class WorkoutPage {
  navCtrl;
  workoutService;
  workouts;

static get parameters() {
    return [NavController, WorkoutService];
}

constructor(navCtrl, workoutService) {
  this.navCtrl = navCtrl;
  this.workoutService = workoutService;
  this.workoutService.getWorkouts().subscribe(workouts => {
    this.workouts = workouts;
  })
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.workoutService.getWorkouts().subscribe(workouts => {
    this.workouts = workouts;
  })
}

workoutSelected(event, workout) {
  this.navCtrl.push(WorkoutdetailPage, {
      workout: workout
  })
}
}
```

This is how I do setRoot after new entry is added to the database.

```
onSubmit() {
  var workout = {
    title: this.title,
    note: this.note,
    type: this.type
   }

  this.workoutService.addWorkout(workout)
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.result = data;
    }, err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log("Workout added"));

    this.navCtrl.setRoot(WorkoutPage);
}
```

I really need a way to refresh data on the Workout page. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using an **observable**

**EDIT**: I've edited the answer because instead of using the observable for syncing both components, you need to use the observable just to be able to change the selected tab once the new item is added.

Since each tab has its own nav history, you can't just use the `setRoot()` method inside one tab, because that's going to set the new page as the root of **that tab** instead of returning the user to the other tab.

So the idea is to use an **observable** to allow one of the child components (the page that inserts the new item) to tell the parent component (the page that contains both tabs) that it should change the selected tab (in this case, the page that shows the list of items).

**TabService**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class TabService { 

  private tabChangeObserver: any;
  public tabChange: any;

  constructor(){
    this.tabChangeObserver = null;
    this.tabChange = Observable.create(observer => {
        this.tabChangeObserver = observer;
    });
  }

  public changeTabInContainerPage(index: number) {
    this.tabChangeObserver.next(index);
  }
}
```

So basically the `TabService` only creates an `Observable` to allow the tabs container to subscribe to it, and also declares the `changeTabInContainerPage()` method that will be called from the child pages.

In the `TabsPage`, we only subscribe to the service, and then we change the selected tab with `this.tabRef.select(index);`

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { Page1 } from './page1.ts';
import { Page2 } from './page2.ts';
import { TabService } from 'tabService.ts'; 

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  @ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs;

  tab1Root: any = Page1;
  tab2Root: any = Page2;

  constructor(private tabService: TabService){
    this.tabService.tabChange.subscribe((index) => {
      this.tabRef.select(index);
    });
  }
}
```

Please notice that we're getting a reference to the Tabs instance by adding `#myTabs` in the `ion-tabs` element, and we get it from the component with `@ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs;`

```
<ion-tabs #myTabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Tab 1"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Tab 2"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Then, the only thing left to be done is to just call that method when the new item was added to the list:

```
    // Add the new item
    this.workoutService.addWorkout(this.newWorkout)
        .subscribe(
          (data) => {

            // Reset the form
            this.newWorkout = '';

            // Change the selected tab
            this.tabService.changeTabInContainerPage(0);
          }, 
          (err) => console.log(err),
          () => console.log("Workout added"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You're a legend. :D This is very helpful and thorough. I'm new to both frameworks. So, I'm trying to play around by building multiple simple apps. I always had problem with re-syncing data.

Comment: I'm not sure why but when I add entry, it gives this error.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of null
    at SyncService.updateListOfItems (sync.service.ts:18)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (add.ts:42)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:225)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:174)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:124)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:88)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:82)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:88)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (xhr_backend.js:68)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:356)

Comment: I really appreciate that. I don't understand it but updateListOfItems() doens't seem to work because when I try calling that method in another page (deleteWorkout), it does the same thing. The page doesn't load but the data is updated.

Comment: Just in case, are you adding `providers: [... SyncService]` in your App component?

Comment: Don't worry, that won't be needed. In 5-6 hr I'll set the plunker and we can work on it.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking forwards to that.

Comment: I've edited the entire answer and added a plunker with the working code. Hope this helps you :)

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you so much for your time. :D

Comment: Np, that's what we're all here for. Glad I could help :)